# homotopic closed paths in topological group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

A topological group $G$ is a group that is also a topological space in which the maps 
$u:G×G → G$ $v:G→G$ defined by $u(g_1, g_2)=g_1g_2$ and $v(g)=g^{-1}$ are continuous.
Let f,h be closed paths in G based at the Identity element e of G. 
Define $f.h$ by $(f.h)(t) = u(f(t),h(t))$ for all $t\in I$.
Prove that $f*h$ ~ $f.h$ ~ $h*f$ and deduce that the fundamental group $\pi(G,e)$ is abelian.

Note the notation $f*h$ ~ $f.h$ means $f*h$ is equivalence to $f.h$, that is $f*h$ and $f.h$ are homotopic relative to $\{0,1\}$.

This exercise is proposed in Kosniowski's "A first course in Algebraic Topology" chapter 15.
I am having trouble solving this and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c_e$ be the constant loop based at $e$. Then $f\cdot h \sim (f * c_e)\cdot(c_e * h) = f * h$ and $f\cdot h \sim (c_e * f)\cdot (h * c_e) = h * f$.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering. may I ask how do you get $(f * c_e)\cdot(c_e * h) = f * h$? are you using the definition of $(f\cdot h)=u(f(t),h(t))$? if so, I think that seems we can get directly $f\cdot h=u(f,h)=f*h$.

Comment: @user138017 it's by direct computation that $(f * c_e) \cdot (c_e * h) = f * h$. If $t\in [0,1/2]$, $(f * c_e)\cdot(c_e * h)(t) = f(2t)\cdot e = f(2t)$, and for $t\in [1/2,1]$, $(f * c_e)\cdot (c_e * h)(t) = e\cdot h(2t - 1) = h(2t - 1)$. Therefore $(f * c_e) \cdot (c_e * h) = f * h$.

Comment: Also, one uses the lemma that for arbitrary paths in topological groups with $\gamma \sim \gamma'$ and $\delta \sim \delta'$ we have $\gamma \cdot \delta \sim \gamma' \cdot \delta'$.